# fixed divs to fluid divs

Tags: html, css, fluid

I'm trying to create a page where the header is 100% wide and takes up 20% of height in a screen with the left navbar (20% width) and a main body adjacent (80% width). I'm trying also to make the page fluid so it maintains it's ratio on different sized screens.

```
html

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="header">


  </div>

  <div class="left">

  </div>

  <div class="main">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

css (with fixed properties commented out)

```
#header{
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #3B3738;
    /*min-height:80px;
    min-width: 100%;*/
}

#left{
    height:80%;
    width:20%;
    background-color: #848484;
    /*min-height:550px;
    min-width:20%;
    position: relative;
    float:left;*/
}

#main{
    height:80%;
    width:80%;
    background-color: #FDF3E7; 
    /*min-height:550px;
    min-width:80%;
    position: relative;
    float:left;*/
}
```

How can I make it so the layout is responsive?

Comment: check out CSS media queries... the answer you seek might be a long one though

Comment: You've done all your widths on % so it will adjust with the window size. If you want the site to be responsive then that means you do not want it to maintain the same ratio no matter of the screen size - it's a bit of a contradiction. Are you wanting it to maintain the ration down (or up) to a certain resolution before adapting the layout in response to the width (such as minimising the menu or making it a one column layout)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your use case is but have you thought about using something like Twitter Bootstrap for this?

http://getbootstrap.com/

There are classes and CSS already written for doing just what it is you're asking. Here is a link to the documentation that explains how the grid system works.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

I hope that is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know I solved my problem by using vh and vw in my css instead of % or px. A clean and simple solution which suits the purpose of my exercise.